# Expect script does not execute on last input from file

Tags: linux, expect

I have an expect script which I use to set my password on large groups of new servers in one go. It reads from an input file which is provided as an argument. It reads the preset password which needs to be changed from one file and the password which needs to set from another. It actually steps through different evaluations and sends input based on what is encountered.

```
set timeout 45
set prompt {\$ $}
set file1 [open [lindex $argv 0] r]
set pw1 [exec cat /home/user/bin/.pw1.txt]
set pw2 [exec cat /home/user/bin/.pw2.txt]

while {[gets $file1 host] != -1} {
    puts $host
    spawn -noecho ssh -q $host
    expect {
        -re $prompt {
            send -- exit\r
            expect eof
        }
        "current" {
            send -- $pw2\r
            expect "New password"
            send -- $pw1\r
            expect "Retype new password"
            send -- $pw1\r
            expect eof
        }
        "continue connecting" {
            send "yes\r"
            expect {
                "current" {
                    send -- $pw2\r
                    expect "New password"
                    send -- $pw1\r
                    expect "Retype new password"
                    send -- $pw1\r
                    expect eof
                }
                -re $prompt {
                    send -- exit\r
                    expect eof
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

puts \r
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the last host in the argument file does not get updated. The prompt for a new password is displayed. Presumably the existing password is then sent and the new password is subsequently sent to the two prompts that follow. However, if I attempt to log in after running the script, the password is not actually set. This only happens with the last host in the list.

What am I missing?

EDIT: Script output:

```
opensuse:bin:6476 $ ./host_check.exp hosts_files/cust_host.txt 
SERVER1
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user user.
Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: SERVER2
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user user.
Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: SERVER3
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user user.
Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
opensuse:bin:6477 $
```

EDIT: Script output with 'ext_internal 1' (sanitized)

```
opensuse:bin:6534 $ ./host_check.exp hosts_files/cust_host.txt 
SERVER1
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {16084}
Gate keeper glob pattern for '\$ $' is '\$ '. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "\$ $"? Gate "\$ "? gate=no
"current"? no
"continue connecting"? no
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: Thu Nov  7 18:55:24 2013 from 10.152.84.124

expect: does "You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)\r\nLast login: Thu Nov  7 18:55:24 2013 from 10.152.84.124\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "\$ $"? Gate "\$ "? gate=no
"current"? no
"continue connecting"? no
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!

expect: does "You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)\r\nLast login: Thu Nov  7 18:55:24 2013 from 10.152.84.124\r\r\nWARNING: Your password has expired.\r\nYou must change your password now and login again!\r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "\$ $"? Gate "\$ "? gate=no
"current"? no
"continue connecting"? no
Changing password for user user.

expect: does "You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)\r\nLast login: Thu Nov  7 18:55:24 2013 from 10.152.84.124\r\r\nWARNING: Your password has expired.\r\nYou must change your password now and login again!\r\nChanging password for user user.\r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "\$ $"? Gate "\$ "? gate=no
"current"? no
"continue connecting"? no
Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password: 
expect: does "You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)\r\nLast login: Thu Nov  7 18:55:24 2013 from 10.152.84.124\r\r\nWARNING: Your password has expired.\r\nYou must change your password now and login again!\r\nChanging password for user user.\r\nChanging password for msnyder.\r\n(current) UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp5) match regular expression "\$ $"? Gate "\$ "? gate=no
"current"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "current"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)\r\nLast login: Thu Nov  7 18:55:24 2013 from 10.152.84.124\r\r\nWARNING: Your password has expired.\r\nYou must change your password now and login again!\r\nChanging password for user user.\r\nChanging password for msnyder.\r\n(current"
send: sending "OldPASS\r" to { exp5 }

expect: does ") UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "New password"? no

New password: 
expect: does ") UNIX password: \r\nNew password: " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "New password"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "New password"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ") UNIX password: \r\nNew password"
send: sending "NewPASS" to { exp5 }

expect: does ": " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "Retype new password"? no


expect: does ": \r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "Retype new password"? no
Retype new password: 
expect: does ": \r\nRetype new password: " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "Retype new password"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Retype new password"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ": \r\nRetype new password"
send: sending "NewPASS" to { exp5 }
```

I've never turned that option on so I don't know how to interpret all of this. It looks simple enough, but there are some bits that make it beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Is the last line of the input file missing a newline?

Comment: Probably. I'll take a look see soon. I'll have to gather another list of servers that I need to run this on to check if that solves the problem.

Comment: Finally getting back to this, @glennjackman. I have confirmed that the issue is present both when there is and is not a newline after the last line of the input file. I'm wondering if it has something to do with not properly sending a newline after the second new password input. I've updated the question with what the output looks like to give an idea of what I mean.

Comment: Is it somethink specific to that particular host that happens to be the last line in the file? Try swapping the last and 2nd last lines.

Comment: Also, reduce code duplication. The "continue connecting" block can look like `{send "yes\r"; exp_continue}`

Comment: Add `exp_internal 1` to the top of the script and  expect debugging output might show you something interesting

Comment: It isn't related to specific hosts. If I run the script against an input file which contains a single entry the same thing happens as if it were the last in a longer list.

Comment: Do a test where that host is not on the last line (i.e. not the only line in the file)

Comment: @glennjackman I've enabled exp_internal. There is a lot going on there so I'm not sure of where to start with it. I also ran it against a file which has only one line (no blank lines before or after).

Comment: @glennjackman Could it be that I'm not sending the right escape sequence? I saw in another question that someone was having issues sending \r\n. I've only been sending \r. The selected answer to that question was to use `set stty_init raw` which made \r\n work properly. I don't know if this is appropriate for what I'm doing, but thought maybe my sequence needs to be changed.